# Emulator device offline

Tags: android-emulator, ubuntu-14.04, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to build android Oreo source code in ubuntu 14.04,it is built successfully but the emulator is not turning on.I tried by restarting the server and check for android devices,it shows that the device is offline and I am not able to turn it on.Suggest a way to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.
link followed-
  https://source.android.com/devices